# Can't add links to table rows in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink

I wrote React function to render table. [That's how the table looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WJpF.png)

As a parameter it takes JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Richard",
    "lastName": "Morrison",
    "numberOfAccidents": 1
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "firstName": "Gregory",
    "lastName": "House",
    "numberOfAccidents": 5
}
```

Part of Table function which render rows:

```
<tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
{rows.map((row) => {
    prepareRow(row)
    return (
        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
            {row.cells.map(cell => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
            })}
        </tr>
    )
})}
</tbody>
```

I want to add link to '/patient/$id' to each row. I tried to write something like:

```
return <td to={‘/patient/’ + cell.getCellProps().data.id} {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
```

and

```
const handlerRowClick = (row) => { history.push(`/patient/${row.original.id}`); }
...
return <td onClick={() => handlerRowClick(row)} {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
```

but it doesn't work. I would like to ask for advice or links which can help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `NavLink` comopenent in `react-router-dom`.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

<td {...cell.getCellProps()}>
    <NavLink to={`/patient/` + cell.getCellProps().data.id}>
        {cell.render("Cell")}
    </NavLink>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `react-router-dom`, you can redirect users on several ways.

1. Using `<Link>` component ([docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link)),
2. Using function `useHistory` ([docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history)),
3. Using `<NavLink>` component ([docs](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)),
4. Using `<Redirect>` component ([dosc](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect))